# Oracle APEX upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: oracle, parsing, load, schema, oracle-apex-5.1

I am encountering an issue with all the data loading processes after upgrading APEX from 5.0 to 5.1.

The context:

```
 - the parsing schema of my app is:  X
 - the table (MY_TABLE) owner (on which the data load process is based) is Y
 - X has the necessary grants on the MY_TABLE
```

Creating the data load process is successful but, when going through the steps of uploading a .csv, after mapping the columns and pressing next an internal error is shown. In debug the error is:

```
could not validate env for schema "Y":context=NULL, parse_as_schema=X, parse_as_schema_override=,sgid=2217918653539024, curr_flow_sgid=2217918653539024, flow_id=110,when parsing
select count( * ) from "MY_TABLE" where rownum <= 10001
```

This error repeats for each data loading process in my application.

If I create a process based on a table from (owned by) X (the parsing schema) everything seems to work fine.

Any ideas on what could be the issue and how to fix it?

*Recreating all the processes using / moving the tables in X schema is not an option for the moment.

Thanks in advance,
Florin

Answer (score 0):

We finally managed to find a (potential) solution to this issue:

It seems that adding the schema Y to the workspace fixes it. Until now, only the parsing schema (X) was visible to the said workspace -  and everything was fine until the upgrade to 5.1.

The only doubt that we have in this moment is if, security wise, we could have issues since we "exposed" also Y schema. The parsing schema for the application remains X.

Thank you,
Florin

Comment: I had same error "could not validate env for schema" in APEX 19.1 when attempting to create new Master Detail Drill Down  pages using two tables from a schema other than the parsing APEX schema (XX_APEX schema in our environment).  We had two possible solutions.  One solution was to add the other schema to the workspace as you did.  The other possible solution was to create a view in the XX_APEX schema which pointed to the real table from the other schema.  We went with the former as you did.  I've not read of others running into this and we only ran into it on Master Detail "Drill Down" pages